# Сменить класс при активном якоре

Tags: javascript, css

Делаю на форуме в комментариях "якорь". Каждому комментарию присваивается уникальный `ID`. Класс имеет такой вид:

```
id="comm1111" class="comm"
```

Если пользователю отвечают на его комментарий, ему приходит уведомление в журнал о том что ему ответили. При нажатии на на ответ его перебрасывает на форум, ссылка выглядит следующим образом: `/forum/topic/id1#comm1111`
Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при переходе по данной ссылке (имеется ввиду если в адресной строке присутствует "якорь") менять класс якоря?
Например: обычный комментарий выводится белого цвета, а если это "якорь", то блок с комментарием должен стать серым.
Насколько я понимаю, здесь нужен JS. Но, к сожалению, я в нём не силён. 
Буду благодарен за помощь!)

Answer (score 1):

можно и без js, если псевдокласс `:target` использовать:

```
#comm:target {
    bacgkround: #f0f;
}
```

Примеры можно, например, здесь посмотреть:
[Трюки с псевдоклассом :target](http://prgssr.ru/development/tryuki-s-psevdoklassom-target.html)